# Using Interface Builder's System Media files in code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, nsimage, nsimageview

I have a question regarding the several images and sound files in the Media tab of IB's library: how can they be used in code?
I want change the image of a `NSImageVew` to `NSRevealFreestandingTemplate`, but how can I access it? I'm pretty sure there must be a better way than creating a hidden image view and pulling it from there. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSImage's [`imageNamed:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-imageNamed_) method to get system images. You can use any of the values found in [NSImage's Constants section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-BCIFACIA) as the name. To get the image you specified, you would use:

```
[NSImage imageNamed: NSImageNameRevealFreestandingTemplate];
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for! I knew apple had implemented something like that... :D

Answer (score 2):

[imageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"NSRevealFreestandingTemplate"]];

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But the other implementation seems a bit cleaner. Yet, this is definitely worth an upvote!